# How to add FTP site in IIS 7 in Windows Vista Home premium edition

Tags: c#

How to add the FTP server in IIS 7 using Windows vista Home Premium Edition?

Comment: This is more of a ServerFault question I think- definitely not immediately related to c# (or programming for that matter).

Comment: I agree, Superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if FTP 7.5 can be used on your Windows Vista machine, http://www.iis.net/expand/FTP

If not, FileZilla is a free alternative, http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server